# Are there exceptions for function arguments?

Tags: c, function, arguments

I am trying to input an argument into a square root function. The function will accept a value b multiplied by b, but it does not accept a value b multiplied by b minus 4. Why is that? How can I get round this? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Function to compute square root of a number

float squareRoot (float x)
{
    float guess = 1.0;

    while (( x/ (guess * guess)) != 1)
    {
        guess = (x/ guess + guess) / 2.0;
    }

    return guess;
 }


int main (void)
{
    float b;
    float valueOne;
    float answerOne;
    float squareRoot (float x);


    printf("give me a 'b'\n");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    valueOne = b*b-4;

    answerOne = squareRoot(valueOne);

    printf("%f", answerOne);

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point equality checks are usually a no-go. Instead of using

`( x/ (guess * guess)) != 1`

replace it with

`( x/ (guess * guess)) >1.0000001 || ( x/ (guess * guess)) <=0.99999999`

which will give you an OK precision in most practical cases.